# Access My Site On Xampp Via Tablet While On Virtual Host

Tags: android, xampp, tablet, virtualhost

I am developing a site on my machine. I am using a Virtual Host, so that my site address for the project is mysite.local.

Typically, I can access my site on other machines on the network by typing `http://ipaddress/projectfolder` (which is in htdocs). But since I am on virtual host, I "can" access it on any computers by pointing the host file to the xampp host machine. But I don't think I can do so on my android tablet, since there is no host file to speak off.

Any advice on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use one of the localhost tunneling tools to temporarily make your site visible to the public Internet - this would allow you to test it from any device that has Internet access, so you can do things like test how it performs over 3G or ask a friend to take a look too.

Two such tools include:

- PageKite - https://pagekite.net/ (disclaimer: I wrote this one)
- Localtunnel - http://progrium.com/localtunnel/

There are others, but these two are both open source with an optional online service component, so you can choose whether you want to run your own relay in the cloud or use one provided by the authors of the tools.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question might not be the most recent, I just ran into the same issue and found another possible solution.

If you want to access one site from within your lan, you can add another virtual host that listens to your local IP, as follows:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.100:80>
  ServerName loc.al
  DocumentRoot "/path/to/project/"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/path/to/project/">
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

That would forward any incoming requests from your local IP to the `DocumentRoot` specified inside that virtual host.

Comment: To your device IP inside your lan. You can find it with `ifconfig` in your terminal.